# ASP.NET MVC strongly typed view convert from C# to VB.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, html-helper, strong-typing

I'm starting to learn ASP.NET MVC and since I work in a VB.NET shop I'm converting an example from C#. I'm trying to implement a strongly typed view and the example I'm looking at shows the following:

```
<tr>
  <td>Name:</td>
  <td><%=Html.TextBox(x => x.Name)%></td>
</tr>
```

I've come up with the following in VB.NET:

```
<tr>
  <td>Name:</td>
  <td><%=Html.TextBox((Function(x As Contact) x.Name).ToString)%></td>
</tr>
```

Is this conversion correct? This seems really cumbersome (I know, I know, VB.NET is more cumbersome than C#, but I have no choice in the matter). If it is correct, is it the best way?

Comment: Just a followup: there's lots of errata in the example I'm following. I believe the problem is that the example is making use of the ASP.NET future's assembly (Microsoft.Web.Mvc.dll from aspnet.codeplex.com) and the correct syntax is `<%=Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name)%>`

Answer (score 1):

Why the call to `ToString` ? The exact conversion is this one :

```
<tr>
  <td>Name:</td>
  <td><%=Html.TextBox(Function(x) x.Name)%></td>
</tr>
```

You probably have an extension method for `HtmlHelper` somwhere else, since there is no built-in overload for TextBox that takes a `Func<Contact, string>` as a parameter... So you need to convert that method as well

Comment: I converted to string because when I didn't VS2008 complained that "Lambda expression cannot be converted to string because string is not a delegate type". As you said, I must be missing something so I'll have to revisit.

Answer (score 0):

I'd think `(x As Contact).Name` would be sufficient, although it has been a while since I tried this with VB.NET...